# Set slice index using reflect in Go

Tags: reflection, go, slice

I'm in Go, working with a reflect.Value representation of a slice. I have the following:

```
slice := reflect.MakeSlice(typ, len, cap)
```

If I want to get the ith value from `slice`, it's simple:

```
v := slice.Index(i) // returns a reflect.Value
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to *set* the ith value. `reflect.Value` has lots of setter methods, for example, if I had a map, `m`, the following is possible:

```
m.SetMapIndex(key, value) // key and value have type reflect.Value
```

But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for slices. My one thought was that maybe the value returned from `slice.Index(i)` is actually a pointer somehow, so calling `v := slice.Index(i); v.Set(newV)` would work? I'm not sure. Ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out I posted this prematurely - my guess that `slice.Index(0)` returns a pointer was correct. In particular:

```
one := reflect.ValueOf(int(1))

slice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.TypeOf([]int{}), 1, 1)
v := slice.Index(0)
fmt.Println(v.Interface())

v.Set(one)
fmt.Println(v.Interface())

v = slice.Index(0)
fmt.Println(v.Interface())
```

prints:

```
0
1
1
```

(Here's [runnable code](http://play.golang.org/p/a3sGq0on0I) on the go playground)

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
n := val.Len()
if n >= val.Cap() {
    ncap := 2 * n
    if ncap < 4 {
        ncap = 4
    }
    nval := reflect.MakeSlice(val.Type(), n, ncap)
    reflect.Copy(nval, val)
    val.Set(nval)
}
val.SetLen(n + 1)
// ...
val.Index(n).SetString("value") // Depends on type
```

Taken from a library I wrote a while back [github.com/webconnex/xmlutil](https://github.com/webconnex/xmlutil), specifically decode.go.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I figured it out tho (sort of jumped the gun on posting a question :D).

Comment: @joshlf13 I notice you've asked a few `reflect` questions. Check out the `xmlutil` linked above, as well as some of the other encoding packages. They should help out quite a bit.

Comment: Ok, will do. btw, if you're interested, the reason that I'm using reflect a lot is that I'm writing a package called "illegal" which provides functions to perform technically disallowed actions (like a generic Map function, comparing two function pointers, etc). It's a private repo on github at the moment (not ready for production yet), but if you have any interest in contributing, I'd be glad to have help on it.